# How should I use placement new with a custom allocation API?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, placement-new

I'm working on some memory space with custom allocation and deletion, which are made using a malloc-like interface, that is not under my control (i.e. opaque C-style functions for "allocate n bytes" or "free an allocated ptr"). So, nothing like `new` or `delete`.

Now, I want to construct an array of `T`'s. I get the space for that with `auto space_ptr = custom_alloc(n*sizeof(T))`. Now I want to do something like array-placement-new to construct the `n` elements in-place. How should I do that? ... or should I just loop from 1 to `n` and construct single `T`'s?

**Note**:

- I'm ignoring alignment issues here (or rather, assuming `alignof(T)` divides `sizeof(T)`). If you want to address alignment, that would be even better, but you may ignore it for simplicity.
- C++11 code welcome (preferred, in fact), but no C++14/17.

Comment: There's a version of placement new for arrays... but there could be alignment issues. Is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01699890c4ae1ac0) what you need?

Comment: @AndyG: Probably not, because placement `new[]` uses some space to write information to be used by `delete[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume your memory is sufficiently aligned for your `T`.  You probably want to check that.

The next problem is exceptions.  We should really write two versions, one with the possibility that constructing will cause an exception, and one without.

I'll write the exception safe version.

```
template<class T, class...Args>
T* construct_n_exception_safe( std::size_t n, void* here, Args&&...args ) {
  auto ptr = [here](std::size_t i)->void*{
    return static_cast<T*>(here)+i;
  };
  for( std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
    try {
      new(ptr(i)) T(args...);
    } catch( ... ) {
      try {
        for (auto j = i; j > 0; --j) {
          ptr(j-1)->~T();
        }
      } catch ( ... ) {
        exit(-1);
      }
      throw;
    }
  }
  return static_cast<T*>(here);
}
```

and the not exception safe version:

```
template<class T, class...Args>
T* construct_n_not_exception_safe( std::size_t n, void* here, Args&&...args ) {
  auto ptr = [here](std::size_t i)->void*{
    return static_cast<T*>(here)+i;
  };
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    new (ptr(i)) T(args...);
  }
  return static_cast<T*>(here);
}
```

You can do a tag-dispatch based system to pick between them depending on if constructing `T` from `Args&...` throws or not.  If it throws, and `->~T()` is non-trivial, use the exception-safe one.

C++17 exposes some new functions to do exactly these tasks.  They probably handle corner cases mine don't.

---

If you are trying to emulate `new[]` and `delete[]`, if `T` has a non-trivial dtor you'll have to embed how many `T` you created in the block.

The typical way to do this is to ask for extra room for the count at the *front* of the block.  Ie, ask for `sizeof(T)*N+K`, where `K` may be `sizeof(std::size_t)`.

Now in your `new[]` emulator, stuff `N` into the first bit, and then call `construct_n` on the block right after it.

In `delete[]`, subtract `sizeof(std::size_t)` from the passed in pointer, read `N` and then destroy the objects (from right-to-left to mirror construction order).

All this will need careful `try`-`catch`.

If, however, `~T()` is trivial, both your emulated `new[]` and `delete[]` do not store that extra `std::size_t` nor do they read it.

(Note that this is how to *emulate* `new[]` and `delete[]`.  How exactly `new[]` and `delete[]` work is implementation dependant.  I'm just sketching out one way you can emulate them, it may not be compatible with how they work on your system.  For example, some ABIs might always store `N` even if `->~T()` is trivial, or a myriad of other variations.)

---

As noted by OP, you might also want to check for trivial construction prior to bothering with the above.

Comment: How confident are we that this will be optimized away for T's with a trivial constructor? Also, why exit(-1) on the destruction throwing?

Comment: @einpoklum Because we are already handing a throw at that point.  Construction threw.  A destructor threw.  We are basically screwed.  I'm not confident in it being optimized away; I'd check for that as well: but I would first implement the above, and confirm it does cause needless looping.  At the least, that detection and skipping of the trivial bit will make debugging less ridiculous.  :)  You'd use tag dispatching and `std::is_trivial` or somesuch.

Comment: Be careful when putting a `size_t` at the beginning of an allocation. The allocation itself is typically aligned, but the additional `size_t` can cause misalignment. I've run into this issue in a real-world application, where clang used SIMD to initialize two doubles in a class, requiring the full `alignof(max_align_t)` guaranteed by StdLib `new`/`malloc`, whereas `sizeof(size_t) < alignof(max_align_t)` on this typical x64 setup.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can "plug-in" an allocation logic, together with a matching deallocation logic, to the builtin new expression.  That can be done with custom operator new and operator delete.  The placement new expression actually takes an arbitrary number of placement arguments; these arguments are used to find an overloaded operator new, also an overloaded operator delete if any.  New expression will call that operator new to allocate memory and construct the object.  If construction of an array throwed an exception halfway, the compiler will destroy those finished objects for you, and call the matching operator delete at the end.

Example code using STL allocator like interface:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

// tag type to select our overloads
struct use_allocator_t {
  explicit use_allocator_t() = default;
};

// single-object forms skipped, just the same thing without []
template <class A>
void* operator new[](size_t size, use_allocator_t, A a)
{
  using traits = std::allocator_traits<A>;
  return traits::allocate(a, size);
}

template <class A>
void operator delete[](void* p, use_allocator_t, A a)
{
  using traits = std::allocator_traits<A>;
  return traits::deallocate(a, static_cast<typename traits::pointer>(p), 0);
}

template <class T>
struct barfing_allocator {

  using value_type = T;

  T* allocate(size_t size)
  {
    printf("allocate %lu\n", size);
    return static_cast<T*>(::operator new(size));
  }

  void deallocate(T* p, size_t)
  {
    printf("deallocate\n");
    return ::operator delete(p);
  }

};

struct fail_halfway {
  static size_t counter;
  size_t idx;
  fail_halfway()
    : idx(++counter)
  {
    printf("I am %lu\n", idx);
    if (idx == 5)
      throw 42;
  }
  ~fail_halfway()
  {
    printf("%lu dying\n", idx);
  }
};

size_t fail_halfway::counter = 0;

int main()
{

  barfing_allocator<fail_halfway> a;

  try {
    new (use_allocator_t(), a) fail_halfway[10];
  } catch(int) {
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

The code will print:

```
allocate 88
I am 1
I am 2
I am 3
I am 4
I am 5
4 dying
3 dying
2 dying
1 dying
deallocate
```